# GeoServer 2.23: wps-service: OperationsMetaData ows:Get xlink:href / ows:Post xlink:href not set / how to set it?

Tags: geoserver, wps, getcapabilities, ows

I'm running a GeoServer locally on docker and in an cloud environment. On docker everything works fine but in the cloud the hrefs of "ows:Get / ows:Post" are not set from the WPS-Service.

If I open this
`https://mydomain/geoserver/ows?service=WPS&version=1.0.0&request=GetCapabilities`
I'll get this response (which is wrong)

```xml
<ows:OperationsMetadata>
  <ows:Operation name="GetCapabilities">
    <ows:DCP>
      <ows:HTTP>
        <ows:Get xlink:href="" />
        <ows:Post xlink:href="" />
      </ows:HTTP>
    </ows:DCP>
  </ows:Operation>
  <ows:Operation name="DescribeProcess">
    <ows:DCP>
      <ows:HTTP>
        <ows:Get xlink:href="" />
        <ows:Post xlink:href="" />
      </ows:HTTP>
    </ows:DCP>
  </ows:Operation>
  <ows:Operation name="Execute">
    <ows:DCP>
      <ows:HTTP>
        <ows:Get xlink:href="" />
        <ows:Post xlink:href="" />
      </ows:HTTP>
    </ows:DCP>
  </ows:Operation>
</ows:OperationsMetadata>;
```

But on docker everything works fine (I'm using here the same version). What am I missing?

**cloud**: The geoserver-gui in **Global Settings->OGC Services->Proxy Base URL**" is set to `https://mydomain/geoserver` but the web.xml from tomcat contains some strange **ip-adresse/geoserver** and is not empty

Comment: Looks like your proxy URL is set to a blank rather than an empty string, when it should be set to `https://mydomain....`

Comment: **cloud** In Global Settings->OGC Services->Proxy Base URL is set to `https://mydomain/geoserver` but the web.xml from tomcat contains some strange ip-adresse/geoserver.